# Dictonary DataType with random in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a dictionary data type using python 3.2. I am using random method to randomly choose a values in the mydict and print out the value. However, I would like to print the key as well (e.g. Animal: elephant) but I only manage to print either the key or the values. How do I go about it?

```
mydict = {'Animal': ('elephant', 'giraffe', 'rhinoceros', 'hippopotamus', 'leopard'),
          'Fruit': ('strawberry', 'mango', 'watermelon', 'orange', 'durian')}
random_word = random.choice(random.choice(list(mydict.values())))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mydict.values()`, unsurprisingly, gives you the values.  You can use `mydict.items()` to get the key/value pairs (as tuples).

Edit: it sounds like you're trying to do something like this:

```
category = random.choice(list(mydict.keys())
item = random.choice(mydict[category]))
print category, item
```

Comment: But using mydict.items() will return me the whole list. I use random to choose from either animal or fruits first and then choose from the values associate with the keys. Let say after the random method, animal and elephant is chosen, my code can only print out elephant but I want to print out animal and elephant on the screen

Comment: @user1744424: See my edited answer.  You need to do two steps if you want to save both values separately.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I am looking for! Thank you for your fast and efficient respond.

Answer (score 0):

`mydict.values()` will print the *values*, it may not be what you expect:

```
>>> random.choice(mydict.values())
('strawberry', 'mango', 'watermelon', 'orange', 'durian')
>>> random.choice(mydict.values())
('elephant', 'giraffe', 'rhinoceros', 'hippopotamus', 'leopard')
```

I think what you really want to do is to combine all the values of all the keys, select one of the values at random, then find out what key it belongs to.  To do that, first you need to select all the values to randomize them:

```
>>> for i in mydict.values():
...    for v in i:
...       values_list.append(v)
...
>>> values_list
['strawberry', 'mango', 'watermelon', 'orange', 'durian', 'elephant', 'giraffe',
 'rhinoceros', 'hippopotamus', 'leopard']
```

Now, you are able to get random values:

```
>>> random.choice(values_list)
'leopard'
>>> random.choice(values_list)
'strawberry'
>>> random.choice(values_list)
'hippopotamus'
```

Next step is to find out which keys this belongs to:

```
>>> i = random.choice(values_list)
>>> ''.join("%s: %s" % (k,i) for k in mydict if i in mydict[k])
'Fruit: watermelon'
```

By default when you iterate over a dictionary, you will get the keys:

```
>>> for i in mydict:
...    print i
...
Fruit
Animal
```

This line `''.join("%s: %s" % (k,i) for k in mydict if i in mydict[k])` is the long version of this loop:

```
i = random.choice(values_list)
for k in mydict:
    if i in mydict[k]:
       print "%s: %s" % (k,i)
```